# What's a decent performing hasher for std::unordered_map, which treats my Key as a generic block of memory?

Tags: c++, c++11, hash, hashtable, unordered-map

I have a key struct which contains no pointers/references/stl. It's a struct that would be valid to "memcpy" if you wanted. I want to quickly define a map on it, using a generic hash algorithm that just hashes the underlying memory.

> std::unordered_map< MyKey, MyValue, HashMemoryState< MyKey> > resultsMap;

Does the standard library already provide a generic Hasher class like what I'm envisioning HashMemoryState as doing? Or do I have to define it myself?

How can I define 'HashMemoryState' to be a generic hasher class that std::unordered_map will accept when I compile? What light-weight hash function would yield decent general overall performance? I don't expect too many collisions and I don't think specializing the algorithm to my specific struct would make much difference for me. For example, one of the key structs I'll be using is a tightly packed Rubik's cube state. It's already kind of random looking, it just needs a quick hash of some sort.

Comment: While there is a specialization of [`std::hash`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash) for any pointer, it returns a hash of the *pointer* and not what it points to. So the answer to your question is that there is no standard generic specialization.

Comment: There seems to be something suitable buried in the Locale library (used for hashing strings). I won't write an answer though, because that library terrifies me.

Comment: Also, the [Boost hash library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/hash.html) has stuff for building your own hash function, including `hash_range` which should do what you want.

Comment: You could treat your memory as a string and use the hash for that

Comment: But be careful that your structure doesn't contain any padding bytes. While it's safe to `memcpy` padded structures, they might contain arbitrary values, which will spoil your hash.

Comment: Not really because all the instances of the struct would have the same padding is that the same item always hashes to the same value and ideally different ones hash to different values but they might not always.

Comment: see the current standard proposal [Types don't know #](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3980.html)

Comment: @cashcow in the padding, structs don't contain `0`s, they contain arbitrary and undefined values.  Which couod be zero, or maybe 7, or maybe 32.

Comment: and if you initialise them first?

Comment: @cashcow such initialization is not guaranteed to touch padding bytes, nor are padding bytes guaranteed to propogate sanely.  There are next to no guarantees about their state, other than that any state they reach through well formed operations does not matter when accessing the actual fields.  If you start reading them for `==` or hashing, all bets are off.  For example, `Type x=y;` could leave such bytes in `x` different than in `y`.

Comment: You could always memset your object. Now don't tell me that is going to ignore the pad bytes...

Comment: @CashCow: Indeed, if you carefully use `memset` or similar on every object that might be hashed at some point, then you'll get a consistent hash. That's somewhat error-prone though; there's no way to enforce that rule.

Comment: It's your object, you decide how to hash it, you decide how to initialise it. If its POD and so memset is safe and you want to use byte-array hash for it then memset it first...

Answer (score 0):

There is a standard hash for strings, of course, and strings can contain embedded null characters so you could simply treat your data as a string and hash that.

Of course to actually invoke the string hash you'd have to copy your data into a string.

Hashes are constant time, but that means constant with regards to the number of items in your collection. A hash on a string or bunch of bytes might depend on the length of this buffer.